# how to reset input fild without empty string in react.js

Tags: javascript, html

How can I reset the input field if I use it this way?

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState({ email: "", emailError: "" });
   
    const handleEmail = (inputEmail) => {
    if (/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(inputEmail)) {
      setEmail({ email: inputEmail, emailError: "" });
    } else {
      setEmail({ email: "", emailError: "Invalid Email" });
    }
  };

   <Form.Control type="email"  onChange={(e) => handleEmail(e.target.value)} name="email" 
    placeholder="Enter email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use initial state variable, this is one of the best approach to reset states in `react`. If you want to reset seperately then you can give initial values for `email` and `emailError` instead of giving whole initial object

```
const initialState = {
    email: "",
    emailError: ""
}

const [email, setEmail] = useState(initialState);
    
const reset = () => {
  setEmail(initialState)
}
```